# jQuery each() image width

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've got a problem with a jQuery code.

Indeed i want to add each width of every image in a row. So i guess it will be solved with the jquery each() function but i dont know how.

I already know how i get one width of a image but i aint able to total each of them.

So, my first step is to select each image i want to. That works fine, but now every try failed. :(

```
images.each(function(i){
    $(images).load(function(){
        totalImageWidth = totalImageWidth + this.width;
    });
});
```

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
var totalImageWidth = 0;    
images.each(function(index, item){
    totalImageWidth += item.width;
});
```

Try that, using `item` (which has the reference to the individual image)

This code is under the assumption that it is wrapped in a `$(function(){...})` (which waits for the page to be loaded before executing).

Comment: With the use of load here though, he wouldn't be able to use this variable immediately after the each.

Comment: `$(item).load(` adds an event handler to the image's load event.  This will trigger later potentially.

Comment: @kingjiv, true, im not sure why its needed. one minute ill edit my code

Comment: The only adjustment I would make is I would bother calculating this number until all images had loaded. If you try and get the width of an image before it loads, you will get the wrong number and if you use this method, you need to build in a way of knowing that totalImageWidth has finished being added to.

Comment: @Sohnee this code is under the assumption that it is wrapped in a `$(function(){...})`, which i will add to bottom of my answer

Comment: Actually I think it would need to be on document load rather than ready.  Ready fires when the dom is loaded and doesn't wait for images, etc.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Neal, Okay i tried your first suggest that worked fine but i cant access the var out of the each function. 
Your current approach doesn't work. I always get 0 as result, because the images aren't loaded i guess. Any idea?

Comment: @YeppThat'sMe - this need to run after the page has fully loaded, i.e. window.onload = function () { ...code example in this answer... };

Comment: @yeppthatsme -- put the `var x = 0;` outside the wrapper

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var totalImagesWidth = 0;
$("img").each(function() {
    totalImagesWidth += $(this).width();
});
alert(totalImagesWidth);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pkCxL/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.... I used this to create a mobile web application similar to google play with the screenshot container scroll-able vertical.

This would be the HTML:

```
<div id="img_container">
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    ...
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery code:

```
//use window.load to work with all browsers
//with document.ready its not working in chrome and safari
$(window).load(function() {
    var img_width = 20; //start with a specific data, usually 0
    $('#img_container').find('img').each(function() {
        //for each img add the width plus a specific value, in this case 20
        img_width += $(this).width() + 20;
    });
    //if you need the container to have the right width to fit all the images
    $('#img_container').css('width', img_width);
});
```